# WildFly 12 and Java 10 does not recognize annotations

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, wildfly

## What I Have

- Tomcat 9.0.7
- WildFly 12.0.0
- JDK 10
- Maven 3.5.3

## Relevant Files

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.training</groupId>
  <artifactId>BigVoiceWebApp</artifactId>
  <name>BigVoiceWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<!--  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  </build>-->
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>release-profile</id>
    <build>

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
  <build>
    <finalName>BigVoiceWebApp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/PostgresDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

## My Problem

I have servlets like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MemberController", urlPatterns = {"/MemberController"})
@MultipartConfig
public class MemberController extends HttpServlet {
```

The problem now, WildFly somehow does not obey annotations. When I access the URL, this is what I got in my browser (copied by viewing source HTML):

```
<html>
 <head><title>Error</title></head>
 <body>Not Found</body>
</html>
```

I have to declare everything in `web.xml` (adding to previous file) for what I've declared as annotations.

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.example.training.controller.MemberController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/MemberController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I reupload the exact same WAR file to Tomcat, the annotations are read correctly.

My question is, why? And how to make WildFly recognize those annotations?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem with everything the same except I'm using Java 1.8.  Wildfly 12, Servlet spec 4.0 as you have (with or without the proper version spec in `web.xml`).  Have you tried to remove some other dependencies to get to a small reproducible test case?

Comment: I've included a sample project that doesn't work in my setting. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w6im35jH-1IyeZHoIGmO6vaY8nTm2iWo This one definitely doesn't work in my WildFly. Can you maybe try to upload it in yours to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the file.  It's Java 10.  I noticed during the build I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ SampleForError ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/home/scott/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

A similar warning is produced when Wildfly starts up.  Some combination of Wildfly 12 and Java 10 doesn't work right in JEE7 mode.

However, there are multiple workarounds.  If you run Wildfly in [EE8 Preview Mode](http://docs.wildfly.org/Getting_Started_Guide.html#ee8-preview) then it works.  Do this by running either `bin/standalone.sh -Dee8.preview.mode=true` or `bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-ee8.xml`

Otherwise, this works without any changes in Java 8.

As an aside, you're trying very hard to confuse any container you're running in.  You specify servlet spec 4 in your `pom.xml` but then your web.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

So your `web.xml` tells the container that you're using Servlet spec 2.3.  If you really need servlet spec 4.0 then your `web.xml` should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

Comment: I need java 9 and above, because certain features are not present in Java 8. I'll take note about this "Java 8" needs for future WildFly deployment.

Meanwhile, that web.xml actually is generated from maven webapp archetype. I forgot to remove it.

Another thing. Once I fiddled with the files (change branch to another version, working, return to the first branch, do `mvn clean package` and upload the WAR) this again doesn't work. Sometimes the annotation works, sometimes it doesn't. I can't reproduce the problems consistently, but it is consistently not working.